# Как нарисовать арку со смещенным центром окружности?

Tags: svg, d3.js

Как нарисовать арку со смещенным центром окружности, если известно: радиус, высота, ширина нижнего основания. Проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю как расположить (получить точки отрисовки) окружности.

Вот что получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно получится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализую так:

```
p = {
    cx : 250, // Центр по Х
    cy : 250, // Центр по Y
    vertical : 50, // Вертикальный радиус
    horizontal : 50, // Горизонтальный радиус
    height : 100, // Высота
    width : 100, // Ширина
  }

const center_x = p.cx, 
      center_y = -p.cy;

let dy = center_y + p.width/2 - p.height/2;
let d = `M${center_x + p.width/2},${center_y}
             v${p.height}
             h${-p.width}
             v${-p.height}
             a${p.horizontal},
             ${p.vertical},0,0,1,${center_x + p.width/2},0`;
```

Comment: точку конца дуги Вы задаете в команде, она абсолютная для `A` и относительная для `a` то есть Ваша дуга это `a500,500,0,0,1,200,200` примерно, если строить слева направо, вы никак не оперируете центром окружности, дуга строится по начальной и конечной точке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точку конца дуги Вы задаете в команде `arc` (последние 2 числа), она абсолютная для `A` и относительная для `a`, вы никак не оперируете центром окружности, дуга строится по начальной и конечной точке. Вместо этого есть флаги, которые определяют какая из 4 возможных дуг, построенных через 2 точки с заданными радиусами нам нужна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот дуга щагающая на 100 вправо с радиусом 100

```js
let r = 100, w = 100;

let d = `M 100,100 a${r},${r},0,0,1,${w},0`;

document.write(`
  <svg viewbox="0 50 300 100" height="88vh">
    <path fill="none" stroke="red" d="${d}">
  </svg>
`);
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что первые два параметра задаются любые? Но почему `y` конечно точки у вас ноль?

Comment: @doox911 смотрите, команда а написана с маленькой буквы, это значит компоненты команды, которые задают координаты считаются относительно текущего местоположения, те. оттуда куда вас привела последняя команда

Comment: Так проблема в то ещё, что если я делаю радиус больше, дуга должна стремиться к прямой, а она не меняется. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: `a${center_x}, ${center_x}` вот тут должны идти 2 радиуса, для круга они равны для эллипса нет